# 2015 gate question from partial differential equation and based on laplace equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I dont know about such functions which satisfy these conditions given  in question

Let **$$\Omega={\{(x,y)\in R^2 | x^2+y^2\lt1\}}$$** be the open unit disk in $R^2$ with boundary $\partial\Omega$. If $u(x,y)$ is the solution of the Dirchlet Problem:
**$$u_{x x}+u_{y y}  =0 \space\space in \space\Omega$$**

**$$ u(x,y)=1-2y^2\space in \space \partial\Omega$$**
Then **$u(\frac{1}{2},0)$** is equal to

$(a) -1$ $\space$ $(b)-\frac{1}{4}$ $\space$ $(c) \frac{1}{4}$ $\space$ $(d)1$

Can you help me out ?

Comment: DId you try anything at all ? It's hard to know how to help you consturctively without having any context whatsoever.

Comment: x²⁻y² example dont strike in my mind, i was thinking about log⁽x²⁺y²⁾, y/x²⁺y² functions only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see for example: https://nptel.ac.in/courses/111103021/33.pdf

In polar coordinates solution is
$$u=r^2\cos(2\theta)$$
In Cartesian coordinates solution is
$$u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$$
Then
$$u(\frac12,0)=\frac14.$$